# Shadow Blade and UA Psionic Wizard

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, unearthed-arcana

From new [Psionic Wizard subclass:](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-PsychicSoulPsionics.pdf)

> **Psionic Focus**
>
> *2nd-level Psionics feature*
>
> - When you roll psychic or force damage for any
>   of your wizard spells, you can reroll any of
>   those damage dice that rolls a 1, but you must
>   use the new roll.

Does this work with Shadow Blade damage?

Answer (score 5):

## class recommended spell list doesn't normally have access to *Shadow Blade*

The Psionics Wizard subclass suggests you pick from a more limited spell list and *shadow blade* is not on that list.

It's just a suggestion, so you are still free to pick it

### But let's say you did get it, then it would work

One possible way is through a **[Ring of Spell Storing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing)** (DMG, 182). If someone else cast *shadow blade* into the ring and then you used the ring to get it, then yes, it would work with the Psionic Focus feature.

Comment: So the answer is "Yes, but you don't have access to the spell normally"

Comment: The Psionic Spells section reccomends spells that are thematic, but it does not replace the Wizard spell list: *"When creating your Psionics wizard, **consider** spells that are thematically appropriate for that tradition. [...] Here is a list of wizard spells that fit with these themes."* So *shadow blade* is normally accessible to a Psionic Wizard.

Comment: Granted that its playtest material that is still being refined, but I don't read it as creating a more limited spell list. Rather it lists spells that thematically fit without necessarily excluding others.

Comment: @NautArch That's not true, it just suggests some spells that fit thematically. There is no limited spell list.

Comment: Totally fair everyone! Updated.